# On "gluing of morphisms"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

At page 68 in Görtz & Wedhorn 's "Algebraic Geometry 1" book, there is the following text:

> Proposition 3.5 (gluing of morphisms):
>
> Let $X$,$Y$ be locally ringed spaces. For every open subset $U \subset X$, let $\operatorname{Hom}(U,Y)$ be the set of morphisms $(U,\mathscr O_{X \mid U}) \rightarrow (Y,\mathscr O_Y)$ of locally ringed spaces. Then $U \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(U,Y)$ is a sheaf of sets on $X$.

I think I may prove this proposition without the "locality" condition. I am not that confident since oftentimes I gave the wrong proof without noticing... So does this proposition holds if we replace all "locally ringed spaces" by "ringed spaces"?

Comment: I think you might be correct that you can omit the "locally" from locally ringed space. I do not think the argument showing that $Hom(U,Y)$ is a sheaf of sets uses this hypothesis ever...

Comment: Yes, this seems correct, and you're backed up by [Stacks 00AK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00AK) (see especially the final lemma, which says "A similar statement holds for ... sheaves of $\mathcal{O}$-modules.").

Comment: The proposition without "locally" is also true, but it is a different proposition, about a different sheaf!